# Real basic question about Sharepoint users

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I cannot seem to get how this is done.
I've read a bit about using AD, so I assume that Sharepoint can be set up to authenticate against AD?
Besides AD, is it possible to manually enter users and groups in Sharepoint to be used for authentication purposes?
Is it possible to use the two together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use both AD users and groups to authenticate and authorize users inside of SharePoint.

Comment: i just read one cannot create users directly in Sharepoint, all users must come from a user directory provider, sound right?